# Linux:dynamically update a background process about changes

Tags: linux

This may sound bit naive, but I need some information about this query,
query is,

Can a process be dynamically updated about the changes made underneath to the program? If yes, then how can this be achieved in a Linux environment?

For eg:- Lets say if a shell script is getting executed in a background for long, meanwhile if I modify the script, so how to update the process about this change.

Comment: Avoid doing such tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have stated your question, I don't think that is possible. You can't(shouldn't) modify a program that is already executing.

Having said that, I think you should reconsider the way you are thinking about your problem. Why would you need to update the shell script and have it pick up the changes? You can code a solution that will expect changes and allow them.

For example, script `a.sh` could simply be executing all scripts in `/somedir`. Then by adding script `b.sh` to `/somedir`, `b.sh` will be executed.

I know that is a vague example but it really depends on your problem definition which you have not provided much of.

Answer (score 0):

It's near impossible, if not impossible.

Updating scripts on the fly seems weird. You can separate what changes from what stays stable, keeping them in a configuration file, and start, stop, restart, etc.